# Merge unallocated space with Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Ok, so firstly I'm using Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Before anyone asks, the unallocated space is **not** by the Ubuntu partition, it is by the Windows partition, which makes this more difficult. I had looked at doing this while in Windows, but Windows disk manager doesn't show EXT4, and EXT2 volume manager doesn't show unallocated space so...

[Here's a screenshot of Windows disk manager (the 27.60 GB is Ubuntu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r79Jc.jpg)

[And here's EXT2 volume manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M6Bp.jpg)

I'll try and get a screenshot of GParted within 30 minutes, if that helps. Thanks.

Edit: [Here's the GParted screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRw1.jpg)

Possibly relevant, but the Windows partition lists the error "Unable to read the contents of this file system!" Any idea about that?

Edit 2: Another update! Partial success so far, after shrinking the Windows partition I gained about 40GB, which I merged with the Ubuntu partition. There's still 12GB by the Windows, but unfortunately I keep getting an error whole trying to move Windows. I'll figure that out soon. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `merge`, you `move/resize` using gparted.

In your case, it's pretty easy. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and start gparted. In gparted, you `move` your Windows C: partition left, then `move` the 27G Ubuntu partition left, then `resize` the Ubuntu partition to the right into unallocated space.

Just in case Windows complains when you try and boot it, you should have a Windows installation disc ready if you need to `repair` a Windows no booting problem.

Note: **of course, backups are ALWAYS recommended**

**Update:** I reviewed your update that included a gparted screenshot. Gosh your Windows partition is big! I'd shrink it. After moving the Windows partition left using gparted, then boot Windows, and **INSIDE WINDOWS**, using Windows **DISK MANAGEMENT** tool, reduce its partition. Then the rest of my instructions still holds true.

**Update 2:** For your Windows error, run a `chkdsk C:/f` to resolve any file system problems.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi Al, thanks for the help so far! Unfortunately my laptop doesn't have a CD tray, so I assume I should use my live Ubuntu USB, and make a backup beforehand? Also, my recent edit might have some relevant info. :)

Comment: Anothe update! Partial success so far, after shrinking the Windows partition I gained about 40GB, which I merged with the Ubuntu partition. There's still 12GB by the Windows, but unfortunately I keep getting an error whole trying to move Windows. I'll figure that out soon. :) Thanks!